# "Cannot find symbol, symbol: method add (Alumnos), location: class.Alumnos" Aparece que no reconoce el método add

Tags: java, netbeans, crud

estoy teniendo problemas para agregar una row a mi ArrayList, no sé porque me sale que no reconoce el método, si es uno que, creo yo, Java tiene por default. Pero aparece "Cannot find symbol, symbol: method add (Alumnos), location: class.Alumnos." Estoy utilizando netbeans en la version 8.2, por favor si alguien sabe como es que debo hacer para ingresar a los métodos que tiene por default java

```
package com.crud.project;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlumnosDAO {
    Connection con;

    public AlumnosDAO(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    //agregar alumno
    public boolean addAlumn(Alumnos alumno){
        boolean test = false;
        String query = "INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, carrera) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps= this.con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1,alumno.getNombre());
            ps.setString(2, alumno.getApellidoPaterno());
            ps.setString(3, alumno.getApellidoMaterno());
            ps.setString(4, alumno.getCarrera());
            
            ps.executeUpdate();
            test=true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        return test;
    }
    
    public List<Alumnos> getAllAlumns(){
        List<Alumnos> alumno = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM alumnos";
            PreparedStatement ps= this.con.prepareStatement(query);
            
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("idAlumno");
                String nombre = rs.getString("nombreAlumno");
                String app = rs.getString("apellidoPaterno");
                String apm = rs.getString("apellidoMaterno");
                String carr = rs.getString("carrera");
                Alumnos row = new Alumnos (id, nombre, app, apm, carr);
                Alumnos.add(row);
                
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return alumno;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas confundiendo la clase `Alumnos` con la lista de alumnos, todas las implementaciones de `List` tienen su respectivo método `add` como tu dices por defecto, pero al final del bucle while estas llamando a la clase `Alumnos.add()` en vez de a la variable de lista `alumno.add(row)`, esto es lo que te dice el error, no se encuentra el método `add` en la clase Alumnos.

Por cierto recuerda también cerrar los ResultSet, PreparedStatement y demás...